# How do I make stores big money makers?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've been playing the game for about 2 weeks now (on Windows Phone 8.1).  I have 30 main levels and 5 subs.  Some of my shops range in rank from 3-5 and vary in the 1000-4500's for the 3rd character's stock.
The issue is, what determines the capacity of stock?
I have looked into the charater's strength areas (dream jobs, all team members within same related job field/color).  I also looked into when the shops where created(lower levels vs higher levels). etc etc.

I can't seem to find out what makes two shops with similar crew skills and rank be so drastically different in stock capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Stock capacity is based on the store itself. Some stores (particularly food levels) have very low stock levels and restock times where as others (often services) have relatively high amounts of stock and proportionally high stock times.

You can choose which level you get when building a new level buy buying that level from the Store, but this costs bux. Full lists of the levels and their stock amounts can be found on the wiki:
http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Food
http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Service
http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Recreation
http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Retail

You can also increase a level's stock by upgrading it, either with bux or with an upgrader VIP. Dream job employees also double one type of stock each.

The skill of staff only affect the restock speed- not the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to upgrade the ranks of your store.
The formula is (store is at rank l, it takes l + 2 bux to upgrade it one level, for a maximum of 3)
Each level increases the output of that store by 10 %.

Unfortunally, stock cost is determined by the level. The level you get will be random, unless your willing to fork up **a lot** of bux.

Also make sure that you assign workers to that shop who specialize in that skill, as they will earn more for you store, and will give you a one time bonus of some bux.

> Every Bitizen has a skill ranging from 0 to 9 for each of the four commercial level types. The base time to stock product is (number of goods / 10). Each skill point reduces this by 1%, to a maximum of 27% reduction with three expert bitizens (skill nine bitizens).

Source:Tiny Death Star Wiki - http://tiny-death-star.wikia.com/wiki/Bitizens